# Преобразовать URL

Tags: .htaccess

Из **/html/music/index.html** в **/music**

Какой правило RewriteRule это выполнит?

Answer (score 0):

```
1.RewriteEngine On
2.RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
3.RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.имя сайта.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Это редирект. А мне нужно преобразовать URL. Т.е при открытие 2 URL загружалось содержимое 1 URL.

Comment: Это делается в одну строчку, только не могу вспомнить как.